# How difficult is it to actually break someone's neck?

Tags: injury, spine, bone-fractures, chiropractor

As a child I was told "if you break your neck, you die". I was also exposed to people who are paralyzed, due to spinal injuries.

So clearly, it happens.

In action movies and martial arts, there's the idea that you can just spin someone's head, and defeat them with a single, quick movement.

However, chiropractors do essentially that, and in some of the craziest ways possible. There's literally contraptions that look similar to something you could hang yourself with. Ironically, the use and application of these devices puts you quite literally out of your misery, but not by killing you, but by making you more alive.

Example: https://youtu.be/4IBKUgZY6zU?t=649

This actually feels amazing!

So where's the difference?

What force is needed to actually kill someone when attempting to twist their head/spine?

And why don't chiropractors kill more people?

Comment: `"And why don't chiropractors kill more people?"` -- That's actually a good question but it probably has a simple answer. They do kill a few with cervical spine manipulations, and you won't see me ever allowing a chiro to touch me above the shoulders, but it's not because they break necks. More likely it's due to cervical artery dissection that leads to stroke. What it takes to break a neck is probably better asked on a site that caters to military training.